# unable to insert multiple array data from dynamic generated field?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am unable to enter multiple data, it enter only single data. I have tried using for loop and then entering data, using 3 user and 2 task, there is an error previously offset.
[image: offseterror]
[image: error]
[image: recieved an array]
[image: view]

```
public function add($postData)
{
    // dd($postData);
    $c = count($postData['user_name']);
    $t = count($postData['task_name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $user_name = $postData['user_name'][$i];
        $user_email = $postData['user_email'][$i];
      
        $data['insert']['user_name'] = $user_name;
        $data['insert']['user_email'] = $user_email;
               
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < $t; $j++) {
        $task_name = $postData['task_name'][$j];

        $data['insert']['task_name'] = $task_name;        
    }
    $data['insert']['name'] = $postData['name'];
    $data['insert']['description'] = $postData['description'];
    $data['insert']['customer_name'] = $postData['customer_name'];
    $data['insert']['billing_method'] = $postData['billing_method'];
    $data['insert']['dt_created'] = DT;
    $data['table'] = PROJECT;
    $result = $this->insertRecord($data);
    
    if ($result == true) {
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Project created';
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'danger';
        $response['message'] = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: so you want to insert multiple entries of task right?

Comment: @Jaymin not only task_name but whole data, like

Answer (score 0):

As Per lack of question details attached, I am supposing that you want to insert multiple task entry with project name, description etc.

Here is updated code:

```
<?php
// dd($postData);
    $username = $postData['username'];
    $user_email = $postData['user_email'];
    $task_name = $postData['task_name'];
    foreach ($username as $key => $value) {
        $data['insert']['name'] = $postData['name'];
        $data['insert']['description'] = $postData['description'];
        $data['insert']['customer_name'] = $postData['customer_name'];
        $data['insert']['billing_method'] = $postData['billing_method'];
        $data['insert']['username'] = $value;
        $data['insert']['user_email'] = $user_email[$key];
        $data['insert']['task_name'] = $task_name[$key];
        $data['insert']['dt_created'] = DT;
        $data['table'] = PROJECT;
        $result = $this->insertRecord($data);    
    }
```

Comment: not only task_name but whole data, user_name and user_email is basically a dynamic input field generated by jquery as same concept is in task_name. If there is 3 users data with 2 task, data cannot be inserted bcoz in 3rd loop task_name is null. in 3 users data. check image for error.